# Django - not displaying the images (as urls)

Tags: python, django

I'm following a ytb video, step by step and everything works fine except for the images.
I uploaded the link adresses through django admin, but they are not displaying.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)


class Offer (models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content%}
<h1>Products</h1>
<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image_url}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ product.price }} RON</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Adauga in cosul tau</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': products})


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('Produse noi')
```

The code is the same as in the video.
I tried to ask chat gpt if there's something that doesn't seem right but he didn't find anything.
I tried to change the name from "image_url" to anything else but didn't work, as expected.

Comment: I suggest to verify if the field value is actually set or not. Check admin site or try logging the target product image_url.

Comment: Show example of an image URL and specific HTTP error status (see in Developer tools or grab image url from rendered page and open this URL in new tab).

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this will work and this is what I changed:
Added

- More descriptive comments have been added throughout the code.
- `products instead of Product.objects.all()`
- To provide a better representation of the product, the "str" method has been defined within the "Product" model.
- The original "image_url" field has been replaced with an "image" field of type "ImageField".

*Importing the necessary modules*

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
```

*Defining the Product model*

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # Adding a field for the product name
    price = models.FloatField()  # Adding a field for the product price
    stock = models.IntegerField()  # Adding a field for the product stock
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images')
```

*Adding a field for the product image*

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name  # Returning the name of the product as its string representation
```

*Defining the index view*

```
 def index(request):
```

*Fetching all products from the database*

```
   products = Product.objects.all()

    *Rendering the index.html template with the list of products*
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': products})
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your code need to “/“ befor {{product.image_url}}